# How to release Elastic IP in AWS that has been disassociated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-ip

I wish to release my IP (it's already been disassociated) but I got the error below. I don't have a Basic Support Plan, so how do I release the IP without AWS asking technical support?

```
Error
52.45.129.XXX: The address with allocation id [eipalloc-90993xxx] cannot be released because it is locked to your account. Please contact AWS Support to unlock it.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can still contact the AWS support with the basic plan if you have an issue.

The IP cannot be released because there is a reverse DNS record associated with it (generally).

Try to do a `host YOUR_IP`, this should return `NOTFOUND` before you can release the IP

Comment: This is what AWS says "On the Basic Support Plan, you can create account and billing support cases and service limit increase requests, but you cannot create technical support cases."

Comment: I did contact them with a basic plan for an error on their services, they were gentle to help me through the stuff, but it was actually a bug on their side.

Comment: Prob with me is that i can't even access Basic Support Plan unless i start paying. I'm closing my account, fyi. That's why I'm releasing/disassoc my IP

Comment: Did you try to check if there is a reverse DNS associated to this IP?

Comment: You almost certainly used [this form](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) to ask for this EIP to be configured with reverse DNS (which locks it to your account) so you might be able to use the same form to send a message to AWS support.

Comment: Failing that, go to the support center, go to Create Case > Account and Billing Support > Account > Other Account Issues.  You don't need paid support for that type of request.